# Proper placement of words

Tags: sentence-construction

**Question sentence:** I am supposed to suggest the correct rewrite of the emphasized part.

> The Tibetan system of meditation is more closely tied to its surroundings than *Zen meditation*

I thought along the lines of

> The Tibetan system of meditation is more closely tied to its surroundings than *the Zen meditation is tied to its surroundings*

and hence answered "the Zen meditation". However, the answer given is "that of Zen meditation". I don't have any clue how they (khanacademy) arrived at this answer.

Please help me understand why this is the correct choice.

Comment: The definite article isn't correct in "the Zen meditation..." - you would want to write "the Zen *system* of meditation". So, think about the sentence as comparing different systems, and not "Tibetan meditation" and "Zen meditation".

Comment: We often are asked to explain or justify answers given by Khan Academy; however, all too often these answers are incorrect or unjustifiable.  Don't worry if you sometimes disagree with them.

Comment: @Andrew Actually, the official body (CollegeBoard) conducting the exam (SAT) is the one which wrote all this practice material. I honestly feel it's more important for me to bend my train of thought to their, than to figure out the sensible rules of grammar. I appreciate the latter 10x more, but i've got to get good marks on the test as well :P

Comment: @GaurangTandon  If this is an actual SAT question it would be challenged by numerous students, as it's awkward and poorly written.  Legions of professional editors would shake their heads in frustration.

Comment: @Andrew yes, I agree with that. Though the only problem with the concept you suggest is that, unlike the exams you or I are familiar with, real SAT test papers are _not_ revealed to the public. The test booklets are taken back from the student within minutes of test completion. This avoids any chance of dispute being raised by the students, consequently any chances of problem for the CollegeBoard are eliminated. They're smart fellows ^_^

Comment: @GaurangTandon  You overestimate their mystery.  I used to teach the SAT.  Questions can be and frequently are disputed.

Comment: @Andrew Can they? :-O  Who is eligible to dispute? And where do I file the dispute? Edit: Oh, [it costs](http://www.nytimes.com/2008/04/20/education/edlife/strategy.html) $43 -_- I guess that's too much. Sigh

Comment: @GaurangTandon  The questions that end up on [actual SAT sample tests](https://collegereadiness.collegeboard.org/sample-questions) shouldn't contain any flaws, but there's no guarantee that SAT-prep sites like KhanAcademy  will be as rigorous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The Tibetan system of meditation is more closely tied to its
>   surroundings than Zen meditation.

That's a grammatical sentence as far as I'm concerned, if a little wordy.  It could be simplified to:

> Tibetan meditation is more closely tied to its surroundings than Zen
>   meditation.

Teachers of expository prose might want you to stick the word **is** in there:

> Tibetan meditation is more closely tied to its
>   surroundings than **is** Zen meditation.

If, for some reason, we wanted to emphasize that it is a **system** of meditation, we need to compare system to system, not "system" to "meditation", and it is for that reason a writing teacher might demand:

> The Tibetan *system* of meditation is more closely tied to its
>   surroundings than *that* of Zen meditation.

That is, "than that [one, i.e. system] of Zen meditation."

Answer (score 1):

Neither the original nor the Khan Academy alternative are as strictly parallel as possible:

> The Tibetan system of meditation is more closely tied to its surroundings than the Zen system.

Khan Academy's most likely assumption is reasonable: we should compare like to like, either system to system or meditation to meditation.   Comparing system to meditation is less than ideal.   However, to my native reader's eye, Khan didn't improve the sentence.

There is a grammatical difference between "the Tibetan system of meditation" and "that [meaning, the system] of Zen meditation", although the semantic difference may seem negligible.   It makes a difference whether "Zen" is inside or outside the prepositional phrase.   The phrasing "that of Zen" in this context could more easily be expanded to "the Tibetan system of Zen" rather than "the system of Zen meditation".   The grammar is more closely parallel, and the semantics are at least as plausible.

So, no, we can't really help you understand why Khan's alternative is the correct choice.   It is too easy to argue that it is a less than ideal choice.

That being said, I still recommend comparing like to like.

Comment: "The phrasing "that of Zen" in this context could more easily be expanded to "the Tibetan system of Zen" rather than "the system of Zen meditation". " That's a nice train of thought. Never thought of it. While surely it doesn't make sense to me to say  "the Tibetan system of Zen", I feel you're right in saying that _going by the rules of English_, either of the expanded forms could be possible. Thanks for this info ^_^

Comment: Surely?  To my native-reading eye, it certainly would make sense to say "the Tibetan system of Zen".  I'd go so far as to say it's a reasonable topic of discussion, pairing nicely with [the Tibetan tradition of Zen](https://www.amazon.com/Tibetan-Zen-Discovering-Lost-Tradition/dp/1559394463).  Were I sure that the phrase *couldn't* make sense, I'd not have been so bothered by Khan Academy's proposed improvement.

Comment: It didn't feel good to me because it was like connecting two proper nouns of same meaning, like "the Eiffel Tower location of the Taj Mahal".

Comment: They are both proper, but they don't carry the same kind of meaning.  Tibetan relates to a geographical region.  Zen relates to what we might call a religion.  If they did carry the same kind of meaning, then your instincts would match my own.  In "The Northern style of agriculture differs from that of the South", I wouldn't as easily imagine "the Northern style of the South" to be a sensible expansion.  In that context, "that of the South" more likely means "the Southern style of agriculture".

Answer (score 0):

I find the original sentence fully grammatical and unambiguous. The allegedly correct answer:

> The Tibetan system of meditation is more closely tied to its surroundings than that of Zen meditation.

sounds very awkward to me and is unclear. The phrase "that of Zen meditation" seems to refer back to "the Tibetan system," which is presumably not the intention.

Comment: The challenge is that a well-written sentence should compare *like* to *like*.  The sentence isn't comparing Tibetan to Zen meditation; it's comparing how each *system* is tied to its surroundings.  Without a complete overhaul, it's difficult to write this sentence without sounding awkward.